# shortcode preg_replace by php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am learning the language `php`. I have two functions and I want to connect these two and show them in one output `php`.

```
<?php
function link_follow($id)
{
    $title = '';
    $slug = '';
    if ( $id == 44 ){
        $title = 'Follow';
        $slug = 'link/'.$id;
        $read = '<a href="follow/'. $slug .'">'. $title .' : '.$id.'</a>';
        return $read;
    }
    return '-';
}

function content_html($string)
{
    $string = preg_replace('/\[FOLLOW_LINK id=(\d+)\]/i',  link_follow('$1') , $string);
    return $string;
}

$content= 'it is a test. Link: [FOLLOW_LINK id=44]';
echo content_html($content);
?>
```

out (html);

```
it is a test. Link: -
```

But i want to show the output (`html`) as below:

```
it is a test. Link: <a href="follow/link/44">Follow : 44</a>
```

It should show this code `<a href="follow/link/44">Follow : 44</a>`.
I think this code `preg_replace` does not work.

Comment: Have you checked what $id is in the `link_follow()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the string `'$1'` you passed to the function has no special meaning, you should use the [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[FOLLOW_LINK id=(\d+)\]/i', 'link_follow', $string);

function link_follow($matches)
{
    $id = $matches[1];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$string = preg_replace('/\[FOLLOW_LINK id=(\d+)\]/i',  link_follow('$1') , $string)
```

doesn't work because *link_follow('$1')* is executed before the replacement and since *link_follow('$1')* will return *'-'*, also the replace() will result in *'-'*.

Also if you pass *'$1'* instead of *link_follow('$1')* as the second parameter, the substitution will result as the original string with the search pattern changed to the value that $1 represents (*'it is a test. Link: 44'* in the example).

A possible alternative solution is to use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) which accepts as third parameter an array where the matches are stored, $matches[0] will contain the $0 match and $matches[1] will contain your $1 match:

```php
function content_html($string)
{
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('/\[FOLLOW_LINK id=(\d+)\]/i', $string, $matches);
    
    return link_follow($matches[1] ?? '');
}
```